# can't style xamarin android calendarView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, calendarview

how can i style xamarin calendarView. i've tried but it's not working. also it appears differently on different android API levels.

this is what i have tried so far

```
<CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:showWeekNumber="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Android.Widget.CalendarView` class is a widget that consists of several subviews. The widget itself does not provide any real styling properties/methods. See the API docs:
Xamarin Android: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.CalendarView/
Native Android:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

And it will look different on different versions of Android as the widget will use the theme/style of the Android version on which it is running.

You should be able to use styles and themes to style the CalendarView though. See this Android doc:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

As a very simple example, you could do this to use the Android built in Holo theme:

```
<CalendarView
    ... 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
```

And by following the guide linked above, you can create your own theme to use and even inherit from a built-in theme and just modify it. And setting a theme should keep it looking the same on all versions of Android.